# glossaries: Setting unicode character as entry label

Tags: pdftex, luatex, unicode, input-encodings

Why does the following compile with `lualatex` and fail with `pdflatex` when setting entry label to be Unicode character?

```
% arara: pdflatex: { options: [ '-synctex=1', '-shell-escape' ]}
% arara: makeglossaries
% arara: pdflatex: { options: [ '-synctex=1', '-shell-escape' ]}

\documentclass{elsarticle}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{calc,siunitx}
\sisetup{load-configurations = abbreviations}
\usepackage[automake,stylemods,symbols,
abbreviations,
xindy={codepage=utf8, language=greek, glsnumbers=false}
]{glossaries-extra}

\makeglossaries
\glsnoexpandfields
\glsxtrnewsymbol[text={\alpha},description={spacing},symbol={[\si{\um}]},type=main]{α}{$\alpha$}

\begin{document}
    \glsaddall
    \printglossary[title=Nomenclature]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably for the same reason `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}α\end{document}` fails with `pdflatex`? It just doesn't know what to do with `α`.

Comment: @schtandard so, how to fix it while using a Unicode character in case of pdflatex?

Comment: I think you misunderstand, `pdftex` cannot do that. One of the big selling points of `luatex` and `xetex` is native Unicode support, which `pdftex` just does not have. Why do you insist both on using `pdftex` and typing `α`?

Comment: @schtandard that's rather misleading the inputenc support in (pdf)latex would allow an input α alpha to be defined, just as accented latin is defined.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ok, maybe my choice of words was a bit too absolute (after all, `pdftex` can do anything, even [control a mars rover](http://sdh33b.blogspot.com/2008/07/icfp-contest-2008.html)). What I meant was that `pdftex` is only set up with very limited Unicode support and the need for more would be reason enough to switch to `luatex`, I think. Of course, one could endeavor to extend `inputenc` towards completeness..

Comment: @schtandard if it was Japanese or something I'd agree but European alphabets the work has already been done, /usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/greek-inputenc/lgrenc.dfu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With lualatex `α` is a plain, simple letter. Not different to `a`.

With pdflatex `α` is a rather complicated command, and you can't use commands in such places.

To see the difference you can compile this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_analysis_show:n {α}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

With lualatex you get:

```
The token list contains the tokens:
>  α (the letter α).
<recently read> }
```

With pdflatex you get:

```
The token list contains the tokens:
>  Î (active character=macro:->\UTFviii@two@octets Î)
>  ± (active character=macro:->\UTFviii@invalid@err ±).
```